# Calling C++ static member functions from C code

Tags: c++, c

I have a bunch of C code. I have no intention to convert them into C++ code.

Now, I would like to call some C++ code (I don't mind to modify the C++ code so that they are callable by C code).

```
class Utils {
public:
    static void fun();
}

class Utils2 {
public:
    static std::wstring fun();
}
```

If I tend to call them with the following syntax, they wont compiled (I am using VC++ 2008, with C code files with .c extension)

```
Utils::fun();
// Opps. How I can access std::wstring in C?
Utils2::fun();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You clearly won't be able to call function returning std::string (or using std::string as a parameter) from C.

Comment: @tomekszpakowicz: Not straight away, of course. But it's certainly doable. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193020/calling-c-static-member-functions-from-c-code/3193099#3193099).

Comment: Even harder: member methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// c_header.h
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

void Utils_func();
size_t Utils2_func(wchar_t* data, size_t size);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
//eof

// c_impl.cpp
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
void Utils_func()
{
  Utils::func();
}

size_t Utils2_func(wchar_t* data, size_t size)
{
  std::wstring wstr = Utsls2::func();
  if( wstr.size() >= size ) return wstr.size();
  std::copy( wstr.begin(), wstr.end(), data );
  data[wstr.size()] = 0;
  return str.size();
}
//eof
```

Comment: So, the C caller is responsible to allocate / free memory for wchar_t data?

Comment: This is the way I'd do it too. This kind of caller-allocates style is very common in C libraries.

Comment: @Yan: Yes, this is usually the safest. Allocating resources in one DLL and freeing it in another often creates problems. Also, it raises questions of resource ownership.

Comment: But the caller must know the size of the string before calling Utils2_func(). Sometimes we may want to allocate memory in the function and let the caller free it (e.g. strdup).

Comment: @lh3: That's why the function returns the size if you pass in too small a buffer. You could call the function upfront `size_t size = Utils2_func(NULL,0);` and have it return the size to you.

Answer (score 6):

What about a wrapper

```
extern "C" void Utilsfun(int i){Utils::fun(i);}
```

**Update:**

That is how you can call C++ functions from C, but accessing std::wstring from C is a different matter.

If you really wanted to manipulate C++ classes from C code then you could create an API where the classes are operated on with C++ functions, and passed back to C using void pointers. I've seen it done, but it's not ideal

```
extern "C"
{
void * ObjectCreate(){return (void *) new Object();}
void ObjectOperate(void *object, char *parameter){((Object*)object)->Operate(parameter);}
void ObjectDelete(void *object){delete ((Object*)object);}
}
```

You will have to be very careful about managing creating and deleting.

Comment: How about std::wstring handling?

Comment: @Chris: And who is allocating/deleting the character buffer and how? It is much better to write to a caller-supplied buffer. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193020/calling-c-static-member-functions-from-c-code/3193099#3193099).

Comment: But something may go wrong, when the class is having virtual functions, right?

Comment: @Yan I don't see why it should, all the class operations are on the C++ side. They should act as expected

Answer (score 1):

I think the only solution is to wrap them in C style global functions in the C++ code like:

```
extern "C" int Util2_Fun() { return Util2::Fun(); }
```

I suppose you could also declare global function pointers as externs using some nasty variation of:

```
extern int (*Utils2_Fun)()=(int *())(Util2::Fun);
```

And then call the function pointer directly from the C package using this pointer but there is little to recommend this approach.

Comment: that need to be extern "C" in the first example, or it will be subject to namemangling.

Answer (score 1):

The most common solution is to write a C interface to your C++ functions. That is C++ code which are declared using `extern "C" { ... }`. These wrapper functions are free to call any C++ code they like, but since they're declared `extern "C"`, they won't be subject to name mangling (you can't do namespaces or overloading here).

That ought to be linkable with your C file and you're good to go.

That is, the header file contains

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

  void wrapper1(void);
  int wrapper2(int x);
  char* wrapper3(int y);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The ifdefs are required to shield the C compiler from the `extern "C"`.
And you implement those in your C++ source

```
void wrapper1(void) { Util::funcOne(); }
int wrapper2(int x) { return Util::funcTwo(x); }
char* wrapper3(int y) { return Util::funcThree(y); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper function in your C++ code:

```
extern "C" void Wrapper() {
    Utils2::fun();
}
```

and then in your C code:

```
extern void Wrapper();
int main() {
    Wrapper();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make C++ callable from C by using the `extern "C"` construct.

Answer (score 0):

If you do as ppl say here (using extern "C") beware that you only pass objects to the C function that would compile in C.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any practical use for c++ objects in your C code, so you'll probably want to create some sort of "C Binding" for your C++ code which consists of some number of ordinary functions that are callable from the C, and only return ordinary C data types.  Your wrapper functions can then call all sorts of classes and objects, etc.  But, they provide a simpler C-Style interface for the objects that you can use from C to bridge the gap.  You can also use function pointers in some cases to give the C access to static methods, but it's usually easiest just to create the wrapper, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write global extern "C" wrapper functions or use function pointers to additionally make static class functions known to C. The C++ code can put these pointers in a global structure or pass them to C while calling a C function as a parameter. Also, you could establish a registry where the C code can request function pointers from C++ by supplying a string id. I've these all these varieties being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of all of the source, I wouldn't bother trying to keep part of it as C.  It should be compilable as C++ (or easily changed to make it so).  That doesn't mean you need to rewrite it as C++, just compile it as such.  This way you can use whatever parts of C++ make sense.  Over time, the C code make turn more C++ like, but this will happen slowly as the need arises.

Of course, if you need it to remain compilable in C for other reasons, this doesn't apply.

Answer (score -3):

C is a subset of C++ ..
So u can not call c++ Class members and namespaces in C.

Comment: -1 it is clear that the asker understands this - thus the question